# Form Input Bindings v-model not rendering in a views page in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have question on it for the vue.js I already have a library vue.js in my web application site. Now my problem is when i try to use the Form Input Bindings the v-model this line of code here below

```
<input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
```

what i notice is it says

```
Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test'
```

So i try to see the solution on this one by adding a `@` beacuase laravel  is using blade template. Now when i add a `@` the error is gone but the render goes this way `{{ test }}` . Why does it not rendered correctly in my browser?. Can someone help me figured this thing out?. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA.

Here is my code

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Cases New Invoice | RMTG')
@section('content')

<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
              <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Cases New Invoice</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                        New Invoice</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6" >
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <form action="" method="post">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        <table class="table table-bordered"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th width="150px;">Contact Name: </th>
                                                    <td>{{ $opp->contacts }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Case Number:</th>
                                                    <td>OPP -{{ $opp->code }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Case Name:</th>
                                                    <td>{{ $opp->tax_year }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Item Code:</th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div id="app-item">
                                                            <select name="itemCode" class="form-control">
                                                                <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.value">
                                                                    @{{ item.text }}
                                                                </option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Notes: </th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" name="notes" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>

                                                    <th>Amount: </th>

                                                    <td><input v-model="test" type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" required />

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>VAT 20% Amt: </th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" name="vatAmount" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Total Amount: </th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="text" name="totalAmount" class="form-control" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="pull-right">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                                <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:24px"></i> Save
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-6" >
                                    <h3>Amount Due: £ @{{ test }}</h3>  


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    //Item code
    new Vue({
    el: '#app-item',
        data: {
            items:[
                { text:'Tax Returns', value: 'Tax Returns' },
                { text:'UTR Filing', value: 'UTR Filing'}
            ]
        }
    })


</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: This v-model is in your blade file ?

Comment: yes its in my blade file

Comment: where to put it? outside blade file?

Comment: in a vue template

Comment: not yet much familiar on that. Umm can you show me how?

Comment: Add your vuejs code maybe

Comment: yes i already add vue.js library on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186201/discussion-between-louis-r-and-php-dev).

Comment: the other code in my blade template runs and works well only with this one

Comment: there i updated my post with a code in it

Comment: i only want this line of code here
<input v-model="test" type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" required />